# i keep getting a signal: segmentation fault (core dumped) error while trying to do file I/O

Tags: c

I have a project for a C programming class that i am having trouble with. Its supposed to output simple patterns to a file after some user input. I'm getting a segmentation fault and I'm not sure how to fix it. I have looked at other examples and none seem to be helping. I'm not very good at file I/O so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks for reading!

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PATTERN1 '1'
#define PATTERN2 '2'
#define PATTERN3 '3'
#define PATTERN4 '4'
#define QUIT     '5'
#define SIZE_MIN 2
#define SIZE_MAX 9


void printInstructions();
void printMenu        ();
char getMenuChoice    ();
int  getUserValue     ();
void displayPattern1  (int value);
void displayPattern2  (int value);
void displayPattern3  (int value);
void displayPattern4  (int value);
void printGoodbye     ();
FILE *patternOut;

int main ()
{
   
   fopen("output.txt", "w");
   
   printInstructions();
   printMenu();
  
   switch (getMenuChoice())
   {
      case PATTERN1:
         displayPattern1(getUserValue());
         break;
      case PATTERN2:
         displayPattern2(getUserValue());
         break;
      case PATTERN3:
         displayPattern3(getUserValue());
         break;
      case PATTERN4:
         displayPattern4(getUserValue());
         break;
      case QUIT:
         printf("Ending the program\n");
         break;
   }
  
   printGoodbye();
  
   return 0;
}


/************************************
The funtion below prints simple 
instructions to the user
************************************/
void printInstructions()
{
  printf("This program will make a shape for you.\n");
}

/************************************
The function below prints a menu
for the user to select an option from
************************************/

void printMenu()
{
  printf("\n1: Forward Triangle\n");
  printf("2: Forward Triangle\n");
  printf("3: Forward Triangle\n");
  printf("4: Forward Triangle\n");
  printf("5: Quit Program\n");
}

/************************************
The function below gets the menu 
choice from the user
************************************/
char getMenuChoice()
{
  char returnedValue;
  printf("\nPlease select an item from the menu: ");
  scanf("%c", &returnedValue);
  return(returnedValue);
}

/************************************
The function below gets the size 
of the shape from the user
************************************/
int  getUserValue()
{
  int returnedValue;
  while (returnedValue <= 2 && returnedValue >= 9)
  {
  scanf("%d", &returnedValue);
  }
  return(returnedValue);
}

/************************************
The function below is the first 
shape
************************************/
void displayPattern1(int size)
{
  int row, column;
  for (row = 1; row <= size; row++)
  {
    for (column = 1; column <= size; column++)
    {
      if(row == column)
      {
        fprintf(patternOut, "%d", size);
      }else
      {
        fprintf(patternOut, "*");
      }
    }
    fprintf(patternOut, "\n");
  }
}

/************************************
The function below is the second 
shape
************************************/
void displayPattern2  (int size)
{
  int row, column;
  for (row = 1; row <= size; row++)
  {
    for (column = 1; column <= size; column++)
    {
      if(size - column +1 == row)
      {
        fprintf(patternOut, "%d", size);
      }else
      {
        fprintf(patternOut, "*");
      }
    }
    fprintf(patternOut, "\n");
  }
}

/************************************
The function below is the third 
shape
************************************/
void displayPattern3(int size)
{
  int row, column;
  for (row = 1; row <= size; row++)
  {
    for (column = 1; column <= size; column++)
    {
      if(column > size - row + 1)
      {
        fprintf(patternOut, "%d", size);
      }else
      {
        fprintf(patternOut, "*");
      }
    }
    fprintf(patternOut, "\n");
  }
}

/************************************
The function below is the fourth 
shape
************************************/
void displayPattern4(int size)
{
  int row, column;
  for (row = 1; row <= size; row++)
  {
    for (column = 1; column <= size; column++)
    {
      if(row > column)
      {
        fprintf(patternOut, "%d", size);
      }else
      {
        fprintf(patternOut, "*");
      }
    }
    fprintf(patternOut, "\n");
  }
}

/************************************
The function below prints a simple
goodbye message to the user
************************************/
void printGoodbye()
{
  printf("Thank you for using this simple shape printer! Have a wonderful day!");
   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `fopen("output.txt", "w");`. But `fopen` returns a variable of type `FILE`. So change that line to:

```
patterOut = fopen("output.txt", "w");
```

The reason why it segfaulted was because you tried to use a variable that was not yet initialized.

Comment: that worked, thanks. now i just got to figure out the rest of it